# Why local addresses usually start with 192.168?

Tags: networking, ip, local

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are home networks prefixed with 192.168?](https://superuser.com/questions/146194/why-are-home-networks-prefixed-with-192-168)

Why local network addresses usually are like 192.168.xxx.xxx? Is there any reason they start with 192.168 or is it just a convention?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Convention, see [RFC 1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918):

> The Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA) has reserved the
> following three blocks of the IP address space for private internets:

> ```
> 10.0.0.0        -   10.255.255.255  (10/8 prefix)
> ```

```
172.16.0.0      -   172.31.255.255  (172.16/12 prefix)
192.168.0.0     -   192.168.255.255 (192.168/16 prefix)
```

Out of these blocks the 192.168.0.0/16 is most often used as the default for home routers because it consists of 256 class C networks which all have the default netmask of 255.255.255.0. The other blocks are a class A and 16 class B networks which makes them less suitable for consumer grade devices because of the different netmask required.

See also [Wikipedia:Private Network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) which is not authoritative, but gives a nice overview.

Comment: Downvoted because modern hardware does not use classful addressing anymore.

Comment: @kinokijuf: Funny, because this answer has no reference of hardware or classful addresing. It instead has a reference of modern IANA reservations.