# Actual Public IP different from Public IP shown on ip lookup

Tags: ip, ip-address

When I test my connection on services such as whatsmyip.com, I get 112.134.xx.xx as my public address. When I check the ADSL connection status on my router, it shows a totally different IP address (100.74.xx.xx) as my public address. When I ping (or ssh) both of the above IP addresses, only the latter works.

Lookups on the above IP address shows that 112.134.xx.xx actually belongs to my ISP, and 100.74.xx.xx is a bogon.

I'm trying to setup a dynamic DNS update client and it's catching 112.134.xx.xx as my IP address, which doesn't work. Any idea what's happening here? My router is a D-Link DSL-2730U.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have a public IP address. The 100.64/10 address space is [reserved for ISPs’ NATs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT) (as opposed to 10/8, 172.16/12 and 192.168/16 which are available for the end user), and is not globally routable.

Comment: Thanks! Any workaround I can do to get my dynamic update client with an ISP which uses carrier grade NAT?

Comment: No, and it'd be useless anyway: your computer is not reachable from the outside due to this ISP nat anyway.

Comment: @CorrosiveKid You can't. You will have to use IPv6 (which your ISP should have also provided you already).

Comment: [Downvoted because modern hardware does not use classful addressing anymore.](http://superuser.com/questions/414222/why-local-addresses-usually-start-with-192-168/414223?noredirect=1#comment1209162_414223)